# issue in construct function for dependency injection

Tags: 9

error I am getting : CreateApplicationService::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalwebsite\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php on line 262 and exactly 1 expected

I have this below code:

[image]

nots sure what is the issue in the construct function. I have done the same POC in another module where I called from form.php and it works. Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: this below is the routing which i have defined:


services:
    OAuthTokenManagement.oauthtokenService:
        class: Drupal\OAuthTokenManagement\Service\OAuthTokenService

Comment: You aren't passing the argument(s) in your services.yml file. Also, your class does not implement the proper interface so that (alternatively) `create` would be called when instantiated (ContainerInjectionInterface).

Comment: @kevin :  could you please elaborate more , which services.yml is missing the arguments ? and how we can add. 

do i have to add , is this you were referring to 
class CreateApplicationService extends ContainerInjectionInterface

Comment: I just added and it worked

ApplicationCRUD_POC.createApplication:
        class: Drupal\ApplicationCRUD_POC\Service\CreateApplicationService
        arguments: ['@OAuthTokenManagement.oauthtokenService']

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please, don't post code screenshots. Instead, copy the code in the question body and format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

it was only missing argument parameter in service.yml.

I only added
arguments: ['@OAuthTokenManagement.oauthtokenService']